# Reverse keys with values list comprehension also randomizes index, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, list-comprehension

I have an original dict:

```
my_dict = {'key1':''value1',
           'key2':'value2',
           'key3':'value3'}
```

based on which I generate its reverse keys <-> values, like this:

```
new_dict = {v: k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

which does swap keys for values, but instead of keeping an "orderly order", it switches indices like this:

```
new_dict = {'key3':''value3',
           'key2':'value2',
           'key1':'value1'}
```

It is imperative for me that they stay in the same spots.

I've tried to do `collections.OrderedDict()` but it doesn't help in the generation of the reversed dict.

How can I do this?

Comment: You realize that dictionaries are not ordered... so if you were using a dictionary before, then clearly, it *was not* imperative that they stay in the same order. You are going to have to *start with an `OrderedDict` * and add the items thje order you want to.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Make it into list before I transform it into a dict again? Seems very heavy and I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: You should check `new_dict` .. don't you think so ?

Comment: No, it's not going to stay in the same order that you write the literal in - or at least, it isn't guaranteed to. You *have to use `OrderedDict`s* if you want your dictionaries to be oredered..

Comment: It is critical that you understand "indices" are not being switched. `dicts` **don't have indices**

Comment: Another point: `new_dict = {v: k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()}` <-- If you have duplicate values, then it isn't predictable which old key will be associated with which old value in the new dictionary

Comment: @GregoryNisbet There will be no duplicates.

Comment: That's not true. `{'a' : 'b', 'c' : 'b'}` is a totally valid dictionary. Once you exchange keys and values you will either get `{'b' : 'a'}` or `{'b' : 'c'}`, arbitrarily. It might help if you gave us some examples of input and output dictionaries so we can understand what you want to do.

Comment: You could switch to [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) Even though they are warning _The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon_ ...

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Greg. I've gotten down to the root of the issue after a bit of debgguing. It seems that if my keys / values contain any of the words that other keys / values have, it bugs the hell down. So, my one-liner somehow has to handle the same characters in keys / values. Any ideas? // Edit, seems like this works: dict(zip(dict_item.values(),dict_item.keys())) . How come?

Comment: As others have said, a plain `dict` does not preserve order (unless you use Python 3.6, but as Paul said, that's currently an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied on). FWIW, if I do `print my_dict` with your data on Python 2.6.6 I get `{'key3': 'value3', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Orderdict**:

```
my_dict=OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3')])

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    new_dict.update({v: k})
print(new_dict)
```

And you will get the `value:key` OrderedDict:

```
OrderedDict([('value1', 'key1'), ('value2', 'key2'), ('value3', 'key3')])
```

In python3.6 `dict` are **ordered**(under the CPython implementation).

> dict() now uses a “compact” representation pioneered by PyPy. The
>   memory usage of the new dict() is between 20% and 25% smaller compared
>   to Python 3.5. PEP 468 (Preserving the order of **kwargs in a
>   function.) is implemented by this. The order-preserving aspect of this
>   new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should
>   not be relied upon (this may change in the future, but it is desired
>   to have this new dict implementation in the language for a few
>   releases before changing the language spec to mandate order-preserving
>   semantics for all current and future Python implementations; this also
>   helps preserve backwards-compatibility with older versions of the
>   language where random iteration order is still in effect, e.g. Python
>   3.5). (Contributed by INADA Naoki in issue 27350. Idea originally suggested by Raymond Hettinger.)

By the way if you need the order,and you want reverse the `key/value` why don't you try list of tuples,**so you don't need to worry about duplicate keys problem**:

```
[ (k1,v1), (k2,v2) ]
```

Hope this helps.